# return value that column value found matched with the variables value in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL script use to select the records that `current_status` contains the following variables `@isPending, @isInvoiced, @isRework, @isCancelled`.

```
SELECT  *  
FROM    vw_sale_search vss  
WHERE CONTAINS (( @isPending, @isInvoiced, @isRework, @isCancelled), vss.current_status )
```

However, error message is:

> (Incorrect syntax near '@isPending'.)

display when I tried to run the script.

Comment: Where do you `DECLARE` your variables?

Answer (score 1):

The main container, in this case your current_status column should be placed in the first place. Then the item to be searched will take the second place in [SQL Server Full-Text CONTAINS function](http://www.kodyaz.com/sql-server-2014/fulltext-index-semantic-search-in-sql-server-2014.aspx)

To searching for more than one word, you can use OR syntax in the CONTAINS function

I created sample fulltext catalog and text table as shown in [SQL Fulltext tutorial](http://www.kodyaz.com/sql-server-2014/fulltext-index-semantic-search-in-sql-server-2014.aspx) and prepared fıllowing SQL Select script to use OR with Contains function

```
declare @isPending varchar(10) = 'Data', @isInvoiced varchar(10) = 'Pool', @txt varchar(100)
set @txt = @isPending + ' OR ' + @isInvoiced 
SELECT * FROM TextTable WHERE CONTAINS (textColumn, @txt)
```